# How can I get to know CPU cache size on Windows 7

Tags: windows, cpu, cpu-cache

`WMIC CPU` command displays a lot of information about the CPUs on a machine. It only displays the information about L3 cache, is there a way to figure out the size of L1 and L2 caches using a command or a tool on Windows 7?

Comment: So you want to do this only from the command-line, using no 3rd party utilities? BTW, with `WMIC CPU` I see information returned for `L2CacheSize  L2CacheSpeed  L3CacheSize  L3CacheSpeed`.

Comment: @Karan are there any other third party utilities?

Comment: Got this http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html thanks

Answer (score 11):

To check your cache size check this [checking CPU cache size and speed on Windows without 3rd party tool](http://www.techvigil.com/tips-tricks/379/verify-processor-cache-size-speed/)

Open your command-line (CMD) and type:

`wmic cpu get L2CacheSize, L2CacheSpeed, L3CacheSize, L3CacheSpeed`

This will return the cache sizes of the CPU. All the values returned will be KB.

Comment: You need to include the answer in your post, a link only answer isn't good! The problem with links, is that they go bad. So, if some one in the future were to read this, and the link doesn't work, your answer is meaningless. Please copy the relevant part and cite the source.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Are there no L1 Cache?

Answer (score 0):

I need the number only, because the output was:

```
L3CacheSize
8192
```

But if you need the number to use it later, use:

```
wmic cpu get L3CacheSize | findstr /r "[0-9][0-9]"
```

so the result will be(in my case 8M cache):

```
8192
```